# External data packing did not work! What did i do wrong?

Tags: workflow

I clicked "external data > Pack all into .blend" and when i opened the blend file without my external hard drive plugged in (it contains the external image-as-plane PNG data), the images-as-planes came up as black (not pink).  How do i contain all the PNG files into the Blender file properly?  I would like for it all to be one file if possible!

Thanks!

Comment: Packing single images should work *(with the exception of image sequences)*, if this fails - report a bug.

Comment: Video files and image sequences will not be packed. Painted textures will also not get packed unless they are saved as images first, and packed afterwards.

Comment: The only external data are the images-as-planes PNGs.  They are animated in the .blend file, but they are not imported as sequences.  Is there any other way to move the entire file including the images-as-planes, and not have blender lose track of where the PNGs are?

Comment: OK, so i tried it again, nothing happened.  Am I supposed to be doing more than just clicking "Pack all into .blend" ?  I am using v2.76 on Windows 7.  How do i report a bug?

Comment: After ***pack all into blend*** you have to save the file again